# How to traverse a Huffman Tree recursively in search for an specific element? - C

Tags: c, recursion, huffman-code

I'm working in a Huffman code, and I'm currently at the phase of encoding/decoding the text file into a binary file. I have this piece of code that retrieves a node from the tree along with all its relevant data (character, frecuency, route):

```
EmptyString ( string );
while ( ( c = fgetc ( nameTextFile ) ) != EOF ) {
    nodeHuffmanTree = SearchHuffmanTree ( rootHuffmanTree, c );
    strcpy ( string, nodeHuffmanTree -> route );
    Encode ( nameBinaryFile, string );
    EmptyString ( string );
}
```

Assume that the routes for each of these nodes (0's and 1's) have already been generated. What I want of the *SearchHuffmanTree* function is that, given a character, it searches for said character in the Huffman Tree and it returns me the node that contains it. This is relevant because that node will contain the route that the *Encode* function will convert into a byte.

I know that i can't treat the Huffman Tree like a Binary Search Tree because it doesn't share the same characteristics, so if I want to search for an specific character I'll have to traverse the whole tree.

I've already looked for alternatives without using recursion (and a stack in some) and, althought they are easier to understand, they produce considerably less simple and clean looking codes, so I'd prefer solutions using recursion.

I've already figured out the encoding/decoding part, so this is pretty much the final step towards finally finishing up my code. Looking forward to any help you can give me.

Comment: Hint: Look at the root node, then the left subtree, then the right subtree.

Comment: @immibis You mean traverse the whole tree Pre Order, In Order or Post Order? I already tried that, but the function doesn't seem to retrieve the node with the character I'm looking for, instead the program just stops working. Maybe there was something I've been doing wrong but I can't figure out why. I can edit the question adding what I came up with so maybe you can point out where i went wrong.

Comment: After building the Huffman Tree, you should use it to create a coding array, which is just an array of 256 structs, where each struct contains a bit pattern and a length. That way, the input character can be used as an index into the array for quick lookup.

Comment: @ShadowGeist Well, the actual order doesn't matter, as long as you look at every node. If your program just stops working then you should find out why and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot assume anything about the position of any specific node (i.e. character) in your tree, since the position of the nodes depends on the frequency of the characters and not on their values. Thus, you will have to find a way to traverse the whole tree, without making any assumptions.

There are 2 ways of traversing a graph in general: breadth first search (BFS), which is based on a queue, and depth first search (DFS), which is based on a stack.

Since the DFS is based on a stack, it is an inherently recursive problem. Also, due to the differences in the way the 2 approaches traverse the tree, DFS will be more efficient on average in your case.

How does DFS work?

Well, the basic principle is that if a node is not a leaf, perform a DFS on each of its children. If you choose the order in which the subtrees are traversed, you can take the highest probability path first, which increases your chances of finding the result faster.

Below is a simple pseudocode of the algorithm:

```
DFS(node T, char x) {
    if (T is leaf)
        if (T == x)
            return found
        else
            return not found
    else
        foreach child of T
            if DFS(child, x) == found
                return found
        return not found
```

You can find more details on the Wikipedia page of [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: Does this solution avoid the use of other data structures? I'm already using a stack to generate the routes for each of the nodes in the tree (the stack uses an array of char). I kinda want to avoid the use of a second stack to store other type of elements.

Comment: Yes, it does. You can use the recursion stack, which you don't have to implement. Actually, I am using it in the pseudocode I've shown.

Comment: Just one question. That pseudocode is for a generic tree. How can i translate the part `foreach child of T` into my particular case which is a tree with just two children?

Comment: In the else branch you can call DFS for each child of the given node, whitout a for loop (i.e. DFS(node.left, x) and DFS(node.right, x)). Note that you may need to check if the children actually exist